# Can I sum the total value of 3 columns in a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have 3 Fields showing 'number of rewards' available that are decimal inputs.

Is there a way I can display a sum of the 3 columns in a field in a data extension so that number can be used in email personalisation?

EG:

```
Field a - 2
Field b - 6
Field c - 1

Sum
Total - 8
```

Alternatively, is this possible with AMP script?

also, is it possible to combine with a Lookup if data is stored in a separate table and linked through a contact id?

EG - %%[set @contactId =[ContactId]]%%
%%=Lookup('othertable','field1','ContactID',@contactId)=%%

Something like:

%%[set @contactId =[ContactId]]%%
%%[set @field1 =[%%=Lookup('othertable','field1','ContactID',@contactId)=%%]
%%[set @field2 =[%%=Lookup('othertable','field1','ContactID',@contactId)=%%]
%%[
SET @total = Add(field1,field2)
]%%

disclaimer - this doesn't work, but an example of what I'm trying to pull off!

Answer (score 5):

Yep, this is possible via ampscript and SQL.
For SQL you would need to run a query as a update.
This should work:

```
SELECT (field1+field2+field3) AS TotalSum 
FROM TableName
```

Ampscript solution using the [Add function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Add.htm) (assuming field1 and field 2 are in sendable DE)

```
%%[
SET @total = Add(field1,field2)
SET @total = Add(@total,field3)
]%%
```

Rounding to the nearest whole number can be achieved using the [FormatNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm?search_text=number) function in Ampscript

```
%%=FormatNumber(@total,"N")=%%
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Can you think of a way this can combined with a Lookup in the case data is updated separately to contact data?

Comment: Have added info in the original question

Comment: as long as you have a a value to look up against in your other table i dont see why a lookup followed by ampscript addition wont work, you should probably use contact key/subscriber key rather than contactID which is a system identifier. When you say it doesn't work what do you mean? are you getting a error. Are you getting results returned from your lookup?

Comment: Hi Noor, yes when trying the snippet of AMP I added as an edit to the original question I got an error message when attempting to preview a test email, I'll revisit again with a fresh set of eyes but I went through every possible variant of field names I could to ensure it wasn't a simple syntax error.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5 contactID is not there as a valid personalisation string, as mentioned previously I'd recommend subscriberKey

Comment: Hi Noor, we have other AMPscrits using lookups references on "ContactID' as that is what we have called the subscriber key field in the relevant data extensions and it works fine. I think my issue is I'm trying combine a SET function with a Lookup populating the reference, but i'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: %%[set @contactId =[ContactId]]%% does this return a value? if not, then your lookup wont return results. can you try subscriberkey instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Add` [function in AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Add.htm) and `Subtract` [function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Subtract.htm).

```
    %%[ 
         set @Avalue = Subtract(@a,2) 
         set @Bvalue = Subtract(@b,6)
         set @Cvalue = Subtract(@c,1)
         set @sum = Add(@Avalue, @Bvalue)
         set @sum2 = Add(@sum, @Cvalue)
    ]%%
```

Comment: Add only takes 2 params